# What's the best way to inherit properties in a tree-based structure?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have a simple CMS system, that has a simple tree hierarchy:

We have pages A through E that has the following hierarchy:
A -> B -> C -> D -> E

All the pages are the same class, and have a parent-child relationship.

Now, let's say I have a property I want inherited among the pages.  Let's say A is red:
A (red) -> B -> C -> D -> E

In this case, B through E would inherit "red".

Or a more complex scenarios:
A (red) -> B -> C (blue) -> D -> E

B would inherit red, and D/E would both be blue.

What would be the best way to solve something like this?  I have a tree structure with over 6,000 leafs and about 100 of those leaves have inheritable properties.  Those 100 or so leaves have their properties saved in the database.  For leaves without explicit properties, I look up the ancestors and use memcached to save the properties.  Then there are very overly-complex algorithms to handle expiring those caches.  It's terribly convoluted and I'd like refactor to a more cleaner solution / data structure.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If your problem is performance-related...

I assume you'd want to save on memory of all these inheritable properties (or perhaps you have a *lot* of them), otherwise this can be trivially solved with virtual properties.

If you need sparse inheritable properties, say if you are modelling how HTML DOM properties or CSS properties propagate, you'll need to:

1. Keep a pointer to the parent node (for walking upwards)
2. Use a hash dictionary to store the properties inside each class (or each instance, depending on your needs), keyed by name
3. If the properties don't vary by instance, use a class-static dictionary
4. If the properties can be overridden instance-by-instance, add an instance dictionary on top
5. When accessing a property, start finding it at the leaf, look in the instance dictionary first, then the class-static dictionary, then walk up the tree

Of course you can add more functionalities on top of this.  This is similar to how Windows Presentation Foundation solves this problem via DependencyProperty.

### If your problem is database-related...

If instead your problem is to avoid reading the database to walk up the tree (i.e. loading the parents to find inherited properties), you'll need to do some sort of caching for the parent values.  Or alternatively, when you load a leaf from the database, you can load all its parents and create a master merged properties dictionary in memory.

If you want to avoid multiple database lookups to find each parent, one trick is to encode the path to each node into a text field, e.g. "1.2.1.3.4" for a leaf on the 6th level.  Then, only load up nodes that have paths which are beginning substrings.  You can then get the entire parents path in one SQL query.

Comment: Thanks Steven that was very helpful.  The problem was db-related, so I ended up caching the parent values into memory.  I'm using a nested set data structure, so I am able to get all the ancestors of a node in a single query (though it's slow, like 50ms) and calculate the proper values and store them in memcached.

Comment: Btw, your comparison to how CSS properties are inherited is exactly what my problem is.  But I guess for a browser, the DOM is all in memory, whereas for me, my nodes are all in the database and thus have to be very conscience of how I call the database.

Comment: @chuboy, can you post your problem query to see if it can be sped up?  I suspect that you are using pretty convoluted logic to load your nested records because RDBMS is not very good at modelling nested structures in a single table, thus the need for some trickeries.

Answer (score 3):

There is a data model that allows you to express this kind of information perfectly, that is RDF/RDFS . [RDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) is a W3C standard to model data based on triples (subject, predicate, object) and URIs; and [RDFS](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/) , among other things, allows you to describe Class hierarchies and Property hierarchies. And the good thing is that there are many libraries out there that help you to create and query this type of data.

For instance if I want to say that a specific document `Lion` is of class `Animal` and `programmer` is of class `Geek` , I could say:

```
doc:lion rdf:type class:mamal .
doc:programmer rdf:type class:Geek .
```

Now I could declare a hierarchy of classes, and say that every mamal is an animal and every animal is a living thing.

```
class:mamal rdfs:subClassOf class:animal .
class:animal rdfs:subClassOf class:LivingThing .
```

And, that every geek is a human and that every human is living thing:

```
class:geek rdfs:subClassOf class:human .
class:human rdfs:subClassOf class:LivingThing .
```

There is a language , similar to `SQL`, called [SPARQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/) to query this kind of data, so for instance if I issue the query:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
       ?doc rdf:type class:LivingThing .
}
```

Where `?doc` is a variable that will bind things type of `class:LivingThing`. I would get as result of this query `doc:lion` and `doc:programmer` because the database technology will follow the semantics of RDFS and therefore by computing the closure of classes it'll know that `doc:lion` and `doc:programmer` are `class:LivingThing`.

In the same way the query:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
       doc:lion rdf:type ?class .
}
```

Will tell me that `doc:lion` is `rdf:type` of `class:mamal` `class:animal` and `class:LivingThing`.

In the same way that as I just explained, with RDFS, you can create hierarchies of properties, and say:

```
doc:programmer doc:studies doc:computerscience .
doc:lion doc:instint doc:hunting .
```

And we can say that both properties `doc:skill` and `doc:instint` are sub-properties of `doc:knows`:

```
doc:studies rdfs:subPropertyOf doc:knows .
doc:instint rdfs:subPropertyOf doc:knows .
```

With the query:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
       ?s doc:knows ?o .
}
```

We will get that a lion knows how to hunt and programmers know computer science.

Most RDF/RDFS databases can easily deal with the numbers of elements you mentioned in your question, and there are many choices to start. If you are a Java person you could have a look at [Jena](http://jena.sourceforge.net/), there are also frameworks for .Net lije [this one](http://razor.occams.info/code/semweb/) or Python with [RDFLIB](http://code.google.com/p/rdflib/)

But most importantly, have a look at the documentation of your CMS, because maybe there are plugins to export metadata as RDF. Drupal, for instance, is quite advance in this case (see http://drupal.org/project/rdf